# What the debug_backtrace() exactly works in php?

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling, debug-backtrace

While working on one of my `PHP` project I got a function `debug_backtrace()` at the start of code file as `<?php debug_backtrace() || die ("Direct access not permitted"); ?>` .

While studding on it I got some explanation that it works as:

> Debugging PHP issues in a Drupal website can be anything from quick
>   and easy to seriously problematic. PHP includes a debugging function
>   called debug_backtrace , which will print out the chain of code that
>   leads up to the point where the backtrace function is called.

And When I use `var_dump()` with `debug_backtrace()` I got following result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(61) "C:\xampp\htdocs\folder_name\templates\default\models\home.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(30)
    ["function"]=>
    string(7) "include"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(37) "C:\xampp\htdocs\folder_name\index.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(146)
    ["args"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(61) "C:\xampp\htdocs\folder_name\templates\default\models\home.php"
    }
    ["function"]=>
    string(7) "include"
  }
}
```

I didn't get that what `debug_backtrace()` function exactly work.

Please anyone explain is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Studied links:

[debug_backtrace() from registered shutdown function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241834/debug-backtrace-from-registered-shutdown-function-in-php)

[Debugging PHP Code with debug_backtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781425/debugging-php-code-with-debug-backtrace)

[Assign debug_backtrace() To a variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628744/assign-debug-backtrace-to-a-variable-in-php)

[Print PHP Call Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423157/print-php-call-stack)

[How can I save a PHP backtrace to the error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369275/how-can-i-save-a-php-backtrace-to-the-error-log)

Comment: You mean what it's doing in this case or in general?  In this case if the script isn't called as part of an application, there is no application back trace and so it blocks you just running that particular script.

Comment: As you said that in this case it will block just running the script, that means it work as session ? I'm totally new for this function: debug_backtrace(), will you please explain its general working and how it works in my case.

Answer (score 7):

Giving a basic example...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo "Start...";
print_r(debug_backtrace());

function t1 ()  {
    echo "Start t1...";
    print_r(debug_backtrace());

}

function t2()   {
    echo "Start t2...";
    print_r(debug_backtrace());
    t1();
}

echo "before calls...";
print_r(debug_backtrace());
t1();
t2();
```

Will output...

```
Start...Array
(
)
before calls...Array
(
)
Start t1...Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /home/nigel/workspace/PHPTest/TestSource/part3.php
            [line] => 22
            [function] => t1
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
Start t2...Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /home/nigel/workspace/PHPTest/TestSource/part3.php
            [line] => 23
            [function] => t2
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
Start t1...Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /home/nigel/workspace/PHPTest/TestSource/part3.php
            [line] => 17
            [function] => t1
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /home/nigel/workspace/PHPTest/TestSource/part3.php
            [line] => 23
            [function] => t2
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I hope this shows that all the `debug_backtrace` function does is return what has been called so far.  So when you first call `t1`, it is simply a stack trace of the call to `t1`.  The same for the start of `t2`, but when `t2` calls `t1`, the trace lists the call to `t2` and `t1`.

But also as you can see, that `debug_backtrace` from `Start..` shows nothing, as there are no levels of code that have caused this trace to be printed.

In your case it calls `debug_backtrace` and uses the `or die()` to say 'if `debug_backtrace` returns nothing, then `die()`'

Comment: [This article](https://www.scalyr.com/blog/php-stack-trace-understanding-debug/) might be useful for users who don't know about [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).

Answer (score 1):

I think the most useful method for debug_backtrace() is to trace which file is the init one start the core, example like

```
a.php
include 'b.php';

b.php
function test(){
     echo('whatever');
}
print_r(debug_backtrace())

php a.php


whateverArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /opt/php/b.php
            [line] => 7
            [function] => test
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /opt/php/a.php
            [line] => 3
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /opt/php/b.php
                )

            [function] => include
        )

)
```

So, you can get from

```
$backtrace = debug_backtrace()
echo $backtrace[count($backtrace) - 1]['file'];
```

Get the file who start the calling